# PDO Exception when accessing a matrix field

Tags: matrix

This is a really strange issue - everything had been working fine for many months then all of a sudden three specific entries in the same section started throwing PDO Exception (see screenshot below). All of the other entries in the section, which use the exact same Entry Types, work fine.

The error occurs when accessing a matrix field that is used throughout the site and works fine elsewhere. I am convinced it is not template related, but at a loss for troubleshooting ideas.

I contacted the hosting provider - Arcustech - but they were unable to provide any insights. Hoping one of you geniuses out there can help!

Running Craft 3.7.26 and using Freeform & Amazon S3 plugins

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? MariaDb or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL 8.0.30 - thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the hosting limit. And there are two possible reasons:

1. Timeout (SQL cannot execute your query because the query is taking too long)
   — `wait_timeout`
2. Packet too big for the server - `max_allowed_packet`

Ask the hosting to increase the values for these MySQL config params

Comment: Thanks, @RomanAvr! That was my thought as well, but I know that the three entries in question are fairly simple and are more or less the same complexity as siblings in their channel. The other point is that this all worked fine before - there have been no structural changes to the site, nothing really new other than new blog posts, so I still wonder what triggered this

Comment: Maybe the hosting provider made changes (maybe when changing the version of MySQL or PHP).
Or have you added content for the matrix block, it has become larger, thereofore, the package size has increased?